# Why does my while command not work?

Tags: python

I don't understand why my code stops working at `print "start with 8"`

Why it doesn't it compare number 8 with numbers 5,8,12,18,22?

```
#Sum of two lowest integers
numbers = [5,8,12,18,22]
keep_ans = []
limit = len(numbers)
for i in numbers:
    print("Start with "+str(i))
    run = 0
    check_in = 0
    Done = False #It's stop here, when i = 8
    while Done == False:
        if i <= numbers[check_in]:
            print("Compare "+str(i)+" with "+str(numbers[check_in])+" round:"+str(run))
            run += 1
            check_in += 1
        if run == limit-1:
            keep_ans.append(i)
            Done = True
ans = sum(keep_ans)
print(ans)
```

Output of my code:

```
Start with 5
Check 5 with 5 round:0
Check 5 with 8 round:1
Check 5 with 12 round:2
Check 5 with 18 round:3
Start with 8
```

Comment: Consider what happens in your `while` loop if neither of the conditionals inside it evaluate to True.

Comment: What's wrong with `while run < limit`?

Answer (score 3):

You are stuck in your `while` loop because in your second iteration you do not enter the first `if`-condition and hence never add 1 to `run` and `check_in`.

To solve this you need to change the indentation:

```
while Done == False:
    if i <= numbers[check_in]:
        print("Compare "+str(i)+" with "+str(numbers[check_in])+" round:"+str(run))
    run += 1
    check_in += 1
```

With this your algorithm will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer!, Thank you.

```
numbers = [5,8,12,18,22]
keep_ans = []
print("Number => "+str(numbers))
for i in numbers:
    print("Start with  >  "+str(i)+"  <")
    point = 0
    round = 0
    limit = len(numbers)
    for i2 in numbers:
        print("     Compare with :"+str(numbers[point]))
        if i < i2:
            round += 1
            #print("     get")
        point += 1
        if round == limit-2:
            #print("Added!!!!!")
            keep_ans.append(i)
            break
    #print(keep_ans)
print("Two lowest numbers = "+str(keep_ans))
print("Sum of two lowest numbers = "+str(sum(keep_ans)))

### Output ###
Number => [5, 8, 12, 18, 22]
Start with  >  5  <
     Compare with :5
     Compare with :8
     Compare with :12
     Compare with :18
     Compare with :22
Start with  >  8  <
     Compare with :5
     Compare with :8
     Compare with :12
     Compare with :18
     Compare with :22
Start with  >  12  <
     Compare with :5
     Compare with :8
     Compare with :12
     Compare with :18
     Compare with :22
Start with  >  18  <
     Compare with :5
     Compare with :8
     Compare with :12
     Compare with :18
     Compare with :22
Start with  >  22  <
     Compare with :5
     Compare with :8
     Compare with :12
     Compare with :18
     Compare with :22
Two lowest numbers = [5, 8]
Sum of two lowest numbers = 13
```